# detection of the ILP mode of BLAS

Tags: fortran, blas

the blas mathematical library is distributed either in the i32lp64 mode (that is, with integer*4 integers) or in the ilp64 mode (with integer*8 or 8-bytes integers).

The question is how to distinguish between these two BLAS modes (i32lp64 vs ilp64) in a short Fortran routine, and without giving the segfault crash.

Comment: You need to make the question more specific. How should make the distinguishing?

Comment: It seems to me that it is too late to test it at runtime. The default integer size may affect too many things and different ones in different compilers. It is not just whether you should pass int32 or int64. Array descriptors for examples, do they use integers or C int internally?

Answer (score 1):

Well,

when you link this program against the ilp64 blas library, we get program crash. In the case of i32lp64 there will be no crash.

And this is the distinction between ilp64 and i32lp64 blas; not very elegant, but doable.

```
program test
integer*8, parameter :: inc = +1_8 + 2_8**33_8
real*8 :: a(3),d
integer :: ii
a(1)=1.0d0; a(2)=1.0d0;a(3)=1.0d0
d=ddot(3,a,inc,a,inc)
print *,"inc=",inc
print *,"d=",d
end program
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a test at runtime by being rather sneaky; it requires understanding the calling conventions on `x86_64` and determining what the values passed to certain functions will look like when interpreted as either 32-bit or 64-bit numbers.  [libblastrampoline](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/libblastrampoline/tree/main) does this whenever it loads a new BLAS library in order to determine whether a library is ILP64 or just LP64.

The [detection code for BLAS is here](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/libblastrampoline/blob/db1f0f227c33bc1fb5c23ddedb79ec87af274582/src/autodetection.c#L94-L140), and is well-commented.  Summarizing it here, we will call a known BLAS function `isamax(blas_int n, float * X, blas_int incx)` with specially-crafted arguments:

```
int64_t n = 0xffffffff00000003;
float X[3] = {1.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f};
int64_t incx = 1;
```

The most important here is `n`, which appears to be a large, negative number when viewed as a 32-bit number, but appears to be a positive number when viewed as a 64-bit number.  Here we are using the FORTRAN-style API but from C, so as FORTRAN expects scalars to be passed as pointers we'll actually do something like:

```
int64_t max_idx = isamax(&n, X, &incx);
```

Now when an LP64 (e.g. 32-bit) BLAS library dereferences `n`, because this is a little-endian system, it will see the lower 32 bits of that value, which is just `3`.  This will then return a value of `2` in `max_idx`, which is the correct return value.  However, if `N` is seen to be negative, this function returns `0`.  This error handling behavior allows you to disambiguate how the library is interpreting your arguments.

LBT contains [a similar method](https://github.com/JuliaLinearAlgebra/libblastrampoline/blob/db1f0f227c33bc1fb5c23ddedb79ec87af274582/src/autodetection.c#L142-L170) for looking at an LAPACK library as well.

The programming language [Julia](https://julialang.org/) uses LBT internally, and it is quite easy to load multiple BLAS/LAPACK libraries and learn all sorts of details about their internal ABIs:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra, OpenBLAS_jll
       LinearAlgebra.BLAS.lbt_forward(OpenBLAS_jll.libopenblas_path; clear=true, verbose=true);
Generating forwards to /Users/sabae/.julia/juliaup/julia-1.9.2+0.aarch64.apple.darwin14/lib/julia/libopenblas64_.dylib (clear: 1, verbose: 1, suffix_hint: '(null)')
 -> Autodetected symbol suffix "64_"
 -> Autodetected interface ILP64 (64-bit)
 -> Autodetected normal complex return style
 -> Autodetected gfortran calling convention
Processed 4949 symbols; forwarded 4856 symbols with 64-bit interface and mangling to a suffix of "64_"
```

So you can see it has dynamically determined the symbol suffix (e.g. `dgemm_` is actually called `dgemm_64_` in this library), the interface type (ILP64), the complex number return style (some libraries/compilers return complex values in an implicit argument), etc...  Compare with a 32-bit build of OpenBLAS:

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra, OpenBLAS32_jll
       LinearAlgebra.BLAS.lbt_forward(OpenBLAS32_jll.libopenblas_path; clear=true, verbose=true);
Generating forwards to /Users/sabae/.julia/artifacts/1f789e077dba9b9c9f09f7ef54f80239bbdf04f3/lib/libopenblas.0.3.21.dylib (clear: 1, verbose: 1, suffix_hint: '(null)')
 -> Autodetected symbol suffix ""
 -> Autodetected interface LP64 (32-bit)
 -> Autodetected normal complex return style
 -> Autodetected gfortran calling convention
Processed 4949 symbols; forwarded 4856 symbols with 32-bit interface and mangling to a suffix of ""
```

Comment: Note that Fortran has been called Fortran, not FORTRAN, for more than 30 years.

Comment: Fair enough; it must be the internal screaming that forces me to capitalize it as such.